# "Texas Instruments PCM2900 Audio Codec" (USB turntable) way too quiet

Tags: sound, usb

I'm borrowing a friend's USB turntable — sony pslx300usb — to record an album, and the USB input is very quiet. I can't adjust the volume in Audacity, or through JACK, and only marginally by overdriving the input in PulseAudio Volume control.

The only slider for this 'card' in alsamixer is PCM, and I turned this up to 100. I tried this on two computers, and both had the same problem. I've toggled between analog and digital input, and this didn't appear to affect anything.

Additionally, my recording had a fair amount of digital ground noise, but maybe that's related to the low input volume. Anyway, I don't see a PCM2900 driver for Linux. I use a USB audio interface, so I know my kernel had the modules installed for USB audio. What should I do?

Lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f3:2494 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:58c2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 08bb:2900 Texas Instruments PCM2900 Audio Codec
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: It will help if you include the output of `lsusb`. Also, just to be clear, you say that you also use a USB audio interface but I'm guessing you are not using that interface now? Additionally, is there a ground wire for the turntable?

Comment: On a side note, on non-USB turntables we usually need to use a preamp to power the output but I don't think that should be the case with a USB output but who knows?